# How can I exit PhantomJS when a specific request is not found?

Tags: javascript, get, request, phantomjs, exit

The problem is, some sites contain the request to test.com/test.aspx and some don't.

If the request exists, it should print the JSON and exit.
If the request does not exist, it should exit too - at the moment, it stays open in this case.

Also, how could I make the code better? Maybe even faster if that's possible?

My JS code:

```
var Url = "http://www.test.de";
var params = new Array();
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var targetJSON = {};
page.open(Url);
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
var match = requestData.url.match(/test.com\/test.aspx/g);
if (match != null) {
    var targetString = decodeURI(JSON.stringify(requestData.url));
    var klammerauf = targetString.indexOf("{");
    var jsonobjekt = targetString.substr(klammerauf,     (targetString.indexOf("}") - klammerauf) + 1);
    targetJSON = (decodeURIComponent(jsonobjekt));
    console.log(targetJSON);
    phantom.exit();
} 

};
```

I tried to add

```
} else {
  phantom.exit();
}
```

and

```
} if (match == null) {
phantom.exit();
}
```

but nothing solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether something doesn't exist, then you need to check all things to see if they are not it or as [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic): [image: ¬∃x P(x) ↔ ∀x ¬P(x)].

You first need to see all requests to see whether your intended request was there. For example like this:

```
var found = false;
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
    var match = requestData.url.match(/test.com\/test.aspx/g);
    if (match != null) {
        var targetString = decodeURI(JSON.stringify(requestData.url));
        var klammerauf = targetString.indexOf("{");
        var jsonobjekt = targetString.substr(klammerauf,     (targetString.indexOf("}") - klammerauf) + 1);
        targetJSON = (decodeURIComponent(jsonobjekt));
        console.log(targetJSON);
        found = true;
        phantom.exit();
    } 
};
page.open(Url, function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("found: " + found); // will always print "false"
        phantom.exit();
    }, 1000);
});
```

I solved this with a global variable which denotes whether the request was found. If it wasn't, then you can exit PhantomJS. If wait until the page is loaded and an additional waiting time in case there are Ajax requests.

Comment: Now it exit if the request is not found, but it stays open if the request is found?

Comment: It should exit in both cases, sorry if I was unclear with my question.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Is there a way to distinguish between found / not found? It should exit immediatly after printing out the JSON without printing anything else, but if the request does not exist Phantom throws an error because targetJSON doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, sure. You can have multiple `phantom.exit()` calls in your code. I added one, now you don't even need the `found` variable anymore. You can tailor the output to your needs yourself. You can take my answer as a template. It doesn't have to mirror your specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I will play around with your template a bit.

Comment: You're probably need the information in another process. You can signal success or failure through the exit code like this `phantom.exit(1)`.

Comment: Yeah, how I can transfer the JSON to my Go crawler is something I need to try this week, running PhantomJS with --webclient:12345 works and serving the output on localhost:8080 works too but how to get it back in my crawler is more complex I guess.